# How to fix "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead"?

Tags: json, swift, decodable

I am trying to decode JSON like this.

this is my data model

```
struct ResponseData: Decodable {
        var AppointMentStatusId:Int!
        var FromTime:String!
        var ToTime:String!
        var AppointmentDate: String!
        var AppointMentStatus:String!
        var DoctorFirstName:String!
        var AppointmentId:Int!
        var Rating:Float
        var DoctorImage:String


        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case AppointMentStatusId
            case FromTime
            case ToTime
            case AppointmentDate
            case AppointMentStatus
            case DoctorFirstName
            case AppointmentId
            case Rating
            case DoctorImage
        }
}
```

I also set init in ResponseData

```
 struct Response:Decodable {
        var Code:Int!
        var Data2:String?
        var Message:String!
        var NoOfItems:String!
        var Status:Bool!
        var Data:[ResponseData]

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case Code
            case Data2
            case Message
            case NoOfItems
            case Status
            case Data
        }

        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
```

I have got problem with this code

```
 if let app = try container.decodeIfPresent([ResponseData].self, forKey: .Data) {// Problem is here
                self.Data = app
            }else{
                self.Data = []
            }

            if let code = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .Code) {
                self.Code = code
            }else{
                self.Code = 0
            }
```

I have set try for all keys

I am trying to handle the nil value of Data key.
When I got Data key is nil it's working fine 
When I got data in Data key it's show error.

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "Data", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

It's my JSON Data

```
{
    "Code": 0,
    "Status": true,
    "Message": "Success",
    "Data": [
        {
            "PatientUserID": 196,
            "FirstName": "gaurav",
            "MiddleName": "",
            "LastName": "",
            "PatientName": "gaurav ",
            "MobileNo": "8585959585",
            "EmailId": "gaurav.sainini@gmail.com",
            "DOB": "2005-06-14T00:00:00",
            "Gender": "Male",
            "RegistrationId": 121,
            "VisitId": null,
            "FromTime": "8:00AM",
            "ToTime": "8:15AM",
            "AppointmentDateForComparison": "2019-07-20T00:00:00",
            "AppointmentDate": "20-07-2019",
            "AppointMentStatusId": 1233,
            "AppointMentStatus": "Booked",
            "DoctorId": 1,
            "DoctorFirstName": "Dr.Doctor",
            "Rating": 3.5,
            "DoctorImage": "http://23.88.103.43:83/Assets/Icons/DoctorIcon/DefaultMale.png",
            "AppointmentId": 250,
            "MemberID": 126
        }
    ],
    "Data2": null,
    "NoOfItems": null
}
```

Please help me on how to handle this error?
Thanks

Comment: Unrelated but **never ever** declare members in a struct conforming to `Codable` as implicit unwrapped optional. Don't do that. Declare it either as non-optional or regular optional (`?`).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the init altogether and make your Data property optional

```
var Data:[ResponseData]?
```

Actually, when I try your init method it works fine. How do you decode? This is how I did it.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(result.Data)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't necessary to use the `override init(from decoder: Decoder)` method and write `enum CodingKeys`. If the keys are the same, it should be decoding automatically.

Comment: When you get response as Data.
You must decode data to Decodable Object..
Example.
`let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let responseT = try decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)                   
`